# Need to set up a responsive (fluid) background image with set height

Tags: css

I am helping a friend setup a web site for his company. At the top of the page, below the navigation bar, I have a background image of a house that is set to 100% width, image size is 2400px x 1602px. My problem is how to control the image so that the house is always front and center. I also need to keep the height at (or around) 75vh.

I have tried using background-size: cover and contain, as well as setting background-positions. But with the way cover works, the house is not always centered. Especially when browser width is larger--then only the roof of the house is visible. Next I tried using the aspect ratio of the image for padding. This works well, but does not allow me to set height (as far as I can tell) so with larger screens I end up with the height being way to big.

Was hoping someone might have a suggestion that would help me out and point me in the right direction. What I would like to have in the end is an image of a house where the house is always viewable and also be able to keep the height @ 75vh. I have a feeling that media queries may be my answer, but wanted some advice before I continue on that path. Also wasn't sure if I need to crop my image to limit the height? I have tried so many different things that I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you for any suggestion, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the background cover image is the right approach, you might just have something wron gin your code that is not centering the image and that is why you only see the roof (top part of the image I assume) instead of the middle part in very panoramic screens.

Here is the code I would use:

This is the HTML

```
<div class="header">Your menu and other header stuff goes here</div>
<div class="bg_image" style="background: url('https://www.marriedwithmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/house-1024x698.jpeg') center center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.bg_image {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 75vh;
}
```

and here is a working example which does what you inted if I understood your situation correctly https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REerRR

Comment: You are correct. I had some remnant code that I was testing with that was throwing things off. I just found it when I was comparing your code to mine. Was also testing wrong too.  Thanks for the info.